# Correct way to specify main and test resource directories in pom.xml for Spring Boot project

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, maven, pom.xml

I have 2 `application.properties` file in my small Spring Boot project. One is saved in `/src/main/resources/application.properties` and the other is in `/src/test/resources/application.properties`.

Some values in **main** doesn't necessarily have to be present in **test**.

**Problem :** When I do maven clean -> update project -> maven install in Spring Tool Suite IDE, I get multiple

> Could not resolve placeholder 'JMS_URL' in value "${JMS_URL}"... and so on

But if I delete the **application.properties** file in **test** `/src/test/resources/application.properties` the error goes away and I get a successful maven install build.

I searched online and found that you need to specify the resources directory in pom.xml if you get that error.

Like so :

```
<resources>
    <resource>
        <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
        <filtering>true</filtering>
        <includes>
            <include>**/*.properties</include>
        </includes>
    </resource>
</resources>
```

In my case, adding that `<resource>` block still did not resolve my problem because it's only specifying the directory of `application.properties` in `src/main/resources` but not for **test**

What is the correct way of handling this kind of situation where you have 2 `application.properties` file in **main** and **test** resource folder?

I'd appreciate any comment.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The correct way of handling this kind of situation is naming the test properties file differently, like `application-test.properties`. Then you either run your tests with the `test` profile active or explicitly specify

```
@TestPropertySource("classpath:application-test.properties")
```

on your `@SpringBootTest`.
Both ways you'll have all your properties from the main `application.properties` and `application-test.properties` active with properties from the latter having a higher priority.

Leaving the test properties file with the default name (`application.properties`) completely overrides the main properties file as you might have noticed. This way the test properties file has to have all the same required properties as the main one for the tests to work.